# yii2 installation - migrate command not working

Tags: php, installation, yii2

I am trying to install yii2 in ubuntu.

yii2 migrate command not working

```
yii migrate
```

I am getting Below error

```
php yii /var/www/event-tracking/migrate
PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ming.ini on line 1 in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: yii
```

Comment: With ubuntu, one have to add `./` before `yii` command and it will work. of course, this command should be invoked after conducting steps mentioned in the first answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After you install the application, you have to conduct the following steps to initialize the installed application. You only need to do these once for all.

Execute the `init` command and select dev as environment.

```
php /path/to/yii-application/init
```

Create a new database and adjust the components.db configuration in `common/config/main-local.php` accordingly.

Apply migrations with console command:

`yii migrate`

or for windows:

```
php yii migrate
```

This command should create the table User,and Migration in your database

ref [[Yii2 Documentation]](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-advanced-app.html)

Comment: Yes i add right details in config/main-local.php. Also try the php command. Can give me details about this function what it create? i think i create required database tables.

Comment: Hi Yatin, I just started using Yii2 on a project, i will explain what i understand: Its easier installing the framework with Composer, using the CURL command to install composer (curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php), then install either basic, advance, or Custom yii application. Basic : (php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic /path/to/yii-application) Advance : (php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced /path/to/yii-application)

Comment: Then you follow this instruction from Yii2  Documentation

Comment: the best answer so far. it just really takes `php init` command in a command line

Answer (score 5):

If `yii migrate` isn't working, you can also try `php yii migrate` as the yii command is just a PHP file that needs to be run.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if You clone the project from the git repo. 
"yii" is added to .gitignore. Follow the instruction described in [yii2 installation - migrate command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531583/yii2-installation-migrate-command-not-working#answer-24532940)
If You'are lazy of afraid to do it for some reasons, just copy "yii" file and /config/*-local.php files into Your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

For init use following command on windows

`c:\php /path of your yii application/init`

For migration:

```
c:\php (path of your yii file which is in your application with file name) migrate
```

e.x:
c:\ php C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\php migrate

advanced is a name of application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
php yii2 migrate

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just had this happen to me, CLI php uses a separate .ini, mine had errors supressed and a config file had a typo I just had to do

```
 php -d display_errors=on yii
```

et voilà

Answer (score 0):

**Error i was getting:-**

user@mohit-pc:/var/www/html/yii2-app$ yii migrate --migrationPath=@mdm/admin/migrations

```
Command 'yii' not found, did you mean:

  command 'ii' from deb ii
  command 'yri' from deb yard

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

---

**Solution Go to the root of you Project and run the  `php yii migrate`**

```
 user@mohit-pc:/var/www/html/yii2-app$ php yii migrate --migrationPath=@mdm/admin/migrations
    Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.43)
    
    Creating migration history table "migration"...Done.
    Total 2 new migrations to be applied:
        m140602_111327_create_menu_table
        m160312_050000_create_user
    
    Apply the above migrations? (yes|no) [no]:yes
    *** applying m140602_111327_create_menu_table
        > create table {{%menu}} ... done (time: 0.041s)
    *** applied m140602_111327_create_menu_table (time: 0.053s)
    
    *** applying m160312_050000_create_user
        > create table {{%user}} ... done (time: 0.034s)
    *** applied m160312_050000_create_user (time: 0.050s)
    
    
    2 migrations were applied.
    
Migrated up successfully.
```