# How to use migrate command in yii2 basic template

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to use migrate command with yii2 basic template i have tried "yii migrate" and also "php yii migrate" but none of them are working. i also tried php init but it says "could not open input file: init".

Comment: windows 7 operating system

Comment: what path in cmd where  to run command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [yii2 installation - migrate command not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531583/yii2-installation-migrate-command-not-working)

Comment: I am using my path to my basic folder

Comment: `init` does not exists in basic template. And show what is the error you get (and everything that is required) otherwise your question may be closed for not being constructive.

Comment: meanwhile read the documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html

Comment: **Yii2 basic** doesn't come with the start migration files as user migration files. You can import those files from **advanced template** and put inside a migration folder.

Answer (score 9):

**Yii2 basic** doesn't come with the start migration files as user migration files. You can import those files from **advanced template** and put inside a migration folder. After that and config your **db** you can run `yii migrate`.

Comment: thanks. That wasn't clear enough on documentation. Stuck on that for a little bit.

Comment: Can you expand on this? What files do I need to import? Right now, my command line says that `migrate/create` isn't a command and plain old `migrate` says "Directory specified in migrationPath doesn't exist". I don't need the migration files necessarily, just the ability to create and execute new ones.

Comment: @EthanC I'll upgrade this answer soon as possible. :)

Comment: Thanks! While information on where to find the RBAC table migrations would be nice, the issue with `migrate/create` not recognized as a command (as well as all other sub commands) had something to do with Git Bash, as it works just fine in Windows CMD

Answer (score 1):

The "controllerMap" configuration is typically used in the application bootstrap file (index.php for web applications or yii for console applications) to configure console controllers.

To configure console controllers using the "controllerMap" component, you need to modify your application bootstrap file (e.g., yii file for console applications). Here's an example of how to configure the "migrate" controller using the "controllerMap" component:

```
// yii (console application bootstrap file)

$config = require __DIR__ . '/config/console.php';

$config['controllerMap'] = [
    'migrate' => [
        'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
        'migrationPath' => [
            '@app/migrations', // path to your custom migrations directory
            '@yii/rbac/migrations', // path to RBAC migrations (optional)
        ],
    ],
];

$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
$exitCode = $application->run();
exit($exitCode);
```

Comment: Please note that the use of GPT/AI tools continues to be banned here.  This answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI.  If you used an AI tool to assist in this answer, I would encourage you to delete it.  For readers of this answer, please validate the answer carefully and comment with any errors.  Users who post low-quality information from AI may be suspended, and the moderation team could use your help identifying issues in the post (if any).